# Rails form_for relation models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi recently I have switched to rails and I'm stuck right now.

I created two scaffolds, connected them like this:
clients got treatments, every client can have more treatments.

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

in the Client model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :treatments
end
```

routes:

```
resources :clients do
        resources :treatments
    end


Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
    client_treatments GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments(.:format)          treatments#index
                      POST   /clients/:client_id/treatments(.:format)          treatments#create
 new_client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/new(.:format)      treatments#new
edit_client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id/edit(.:format) treatments#edit
     client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#show
                      PATCH  /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#update
                      PUT    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#update
                      DELETE /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#destroy
              clients GET    /clients(.:format)                                clients#index
                      POST   /clients(.:format)                                clients#create
           new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                            clients#new
          edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                       clients#edit
               client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#show
                      PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                      PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                      DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#destroy
                 root GET    /
```

When i fire up rails console and input this:

c = Client.find(1)

c.treatments

I got results. 
My problem is, I can't figure out how to make a form for the client.treatments.

i tried this:

```
<%= form_for(@client.treatments) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field "intervention" %>
    <%= f.intervention %>
<% end %>
```

but failed.
How do I have to set up my form for the @client.treatment and how do I have to set up my controller and which controller do I have to set up? 
I'm kinda lost here.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: First of all, where is that view code? Is it the edit action? Where is your ClientsController code? The form_for should be `form_for(@client)` not `@client.treatments`. There is no form helper `intervention` method, so I'm not even sure what the `f.intervention` line is trying to do. Can you be more clear as to what the objective here is?

Comment: It's the treatments/new.html.erb 
I want to create a new treatment for a client.
The controller is scaffold default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this

```
<%= form_for([@client, @client.treatments.new]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use some gem for that like [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields). Then it will be like this:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <div class="items">
    <%= f.nested_fields_for :treatments do |f| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">add treatment</a>
<% end %>
```